# Automapper ignoring BeforeMap

Tags: c#, automapper

I would like to map the response of an external API that is something like the following code

```
public class ListOfPersons
{
    public IEnumerable<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to map to IEnumerable of MyPersonObject

```
public MyPersonObject 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following Automapper Profiler

```
CreateMap<Person, MyPersonObject>();
CreateMap<ListOfPersons, IEnumerable<MyPersonObject>>()
    .BeforeMap((src, dest) =>
     {
         src.Data = src.Data.Take(24).ToList();
     })
     .ConvertUsing<GenericListOfPersonsConverter>();


    class DataPointConverter : ITypeConverter<ListOfPerson, IEnumerable<MyPersonObject>>
    {
        public IEnumerable<MyPersonObject> Convert(ListOfPersons source,
            IEnumerable<MyPersonObject> destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return source.Persons.Select(Mapper.Map<MyPersonObject>);
        }
    }
```

As you see in code I want only get the 24 first persons, but when I execute the mapping

```
var mapperObject = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyPersonObject>(source);
```

mappedObject contains more than 24 elements, the beforeMap is never executed. Any idea because beforeMap is ignored?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know how your real code looks like, but this snippet doesn't make much sense. AM handles collections by default.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tryied out of box and It didn't work. I know that the source data is rare, but I can't change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeforeMap is not called for type converters. Write the event code inside your converter.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are 2 problems. The first: your shouldn't map to IEnumerable since mapper already know how to map to Enumerable:). You can create a new list object(MyPersonObjectList). And the second one: Is it possible to change the converter and get 24 persons there?

```
public class GenericListOfPersonsConverter : ITypeConverter<ListOfPersons, MyPersonObjectList>
{
    public MyPersonObjectList Convert(ListOfPersons source, MyPersonObjectList destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //Take 24 persons here
        return new MyPersonObjectList(){MyPersonObjects = source.Persons.Take(24).Select(p => p.Name).ToList()};
    }
}

public class MyPersonObjectList
{
    public List<string> MyPersonObjects {get; set;}

    public MyPersonObjectList() {
        MyPersonObjects = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. Take into account that I'm trying to do a BerforeMap and ConvertUsing in the same mapping. Evend I added a breakpoint in the beforeMap code but it's nerver executed. I guess that is what @LucianBargaoanu said that BeforeMap is not called for type convertes.

Comment: I've changed my solution, check it please, may be it will be helpful!

Comment: It Is the solution that I've done finally, but I posted for curiosity why the BeforeMap doesn't work. Thanks for your help!!!